# Rails before_filter - destroy user's objects only

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails (just finished the tutorial), I'm trying to restrict deletion of objects to only the owner, but anyone can view it.

Currently if I am signed it (to any account) then when I click 'destroy' nothing happens (no refresh, nothing), but if I am not logged in, then it asks me if I'm sure -> then it checks if I am signed in and will eject me to the sign_in page.

events_controller.rb

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user,  only: [:create, :edit,  :update,  :destroy]
  before_filter :correct_user,    only: [         :edit,  :update,  :destroy]
...
# DELETE /events/1
  # DELETE /events/1.json
  def destroy
    @event.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end
  private
    def signed_in_user
      unless signed_in?
        store_location
        redirect_to signin_path, notice: "Please sign in."
      end
    end
    def correct_user
      @event = current_user.events.find_by_id(params[:id])
      redirect_to root_path if @event.nil?
    end
    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
    end
end
```

Educational explanations are greatly appreciated. Thanks

Rake Routes - as requested

```
         events GET    /events(.:format)              events#index
           POST   /events(.:format)              events#create
 new_event GET    /events/new(.:format)          events#new
edit_event GET    /events/:id/edit(.:format)     events#edit
     event GET    /events/:id(.:format)          events#show
           PUT    /events/:id(.:format)          events#update
           DELETE /events/:id(.:format)          events#destroy
 locations GET    /locations(.:format)           locations#index
           POST   /locations(.:format)           locations#create
   new_location GET    /locations/new(.:format)       locations#new
  edit_location GET    /locations/:id/edit(.:format)  locations#edit
       location GET    /locations/:id(.:format)       locations#show
           PUT    /locations/:id(.:format)       locations#update
           DELETE /locations/:id(.:format)       locations#destroy
       sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)            sessions#create
    new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)        sessions#new
        session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)        sessions#destroy
 following_user GET    /users/:id/following(.:format) users#following
 followers_user GET    /users/:id/followers(.:format) users#followers
          users GET    /users(.:format)               users#index
                POST   /users(.:format)               users#create
       new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)           users#new
      edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)      users#edit
           user GET    /users/:id(.:format)           users#show
                PUT    /users/:id(.:format)           users#update
                DELETE /users/:id(.:format)           users#destroy
     microposts POST   /microposts(.:format)          microposts#create
      micropost DELETE /microposts/:id(.:format)      microposts#destroy
                POST   /events(.:format)              events#create
                DELETE /events/:id(.:format)          events#destroy
  relationships POST   /relationships(.:format)       relationships#create
   relationship DELETE /relationships/:id(.:format)   relationships#destroy
           root        /                              static_pages#home
         signup        /signup(.:format)              users#new
           help        /help(.:format)                static_pages#help
          about        /about(.:format)               static_pages#about
        contact        /contact(.:format)             static_pages#contact
                GET    /users(.:format)               users#index
                POST   /users(.:format)               users#create
                GET    /users/new(.:format)           users#new
                GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)      users#edit
                GET    /users/:id(.:format)           users#show
                PUT    /users/:id(.:format)           users#update
                DELETE /users/:id(.:format)           users#destroy
                POST   /sessions(.:format)            sessions#create
                GET    /sessions/new(.:format)        sessions#new
                DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)        sessions#destroy
                       /signup(.:format)              users#new
         signin        /signin(.:format)              sessions#new
        signout DELETE /signout(.:format)             sessions#destroy
```

Comment: Please share your log what happens when you click the destroy link

Comment: For signed in - nothing, nothing new on the log. for un signed in - Processing by EventsController#index as HTML
  Event Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" 
  Rendered events/index.html.erb within layouts/application (33.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'kGMIrB3zTDbjbSjYvZdvuA' LIMIT 1

Comment: It would probably help to share the form view and the output from `rake routes`.

Comment: @SteveRowley Edited post to include it

Comment: Seems like link issue. Maybe you have set different link attributes for signed/unsigned users?

Comment: Hint: `find_by_id(params[:id])` should just be `find(params[:id])`.

Comment: Check if there is a javascript error in signed-in case

Comment: No luck yet, I am not sure how to check for javascript errors. The html is identical for non logged in users and logged in users (inspect elements).